# Add Image in next line in LinearLayout Programatcally - Android

Tags: android, scrollview, android-linearlayout

I have a LinearLayout with orientation horizontal, but when it cross 4 elements in an one row it keeps adding in horizontal, I want to it automatically changes to the next row, example:

What happens:
[image: Whta happen:]

What I want:
[image: What I want:]

My code:

```
btnAdd.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            countLikesAdd++;
            removeMessageOrShow();
            ImageView iconLike = new ImageView(Register30.this);
            iconLike.setImageDrawable(getDrawable(R.drawable.musicicon));
            LinearLayout.LayoutParams lp = new LinearLayout.LayoutParams(140,130);
            lp.setMargins(5,5,5,5);
            iconLike.setLayoutParams(lp);
            relativeLayout.addView(iconLike);
        }
    });
```

My XML:

```
<ScrollView
    android:id="@+id/svLikes"
    android:layout_width="0dp"
    android:layout_height="0dp"
    android:layout_marginBottom="60dp"
    android:layout_marginEnd="14dp"
    android:layout_marginStart="14dp"
    android:layout_marginTop="48dp"
    android:background="#2f3342"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintLeft_toLeftOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintRight_toRightOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="@+id/btnAdd"
    app:layout_constraintVertical_bias="0.0"
    tools:layout_constraintBottom_creator="1"
    tools:layout_constraintLeft_creator="1"
    tools:layout_constraintRight_creator="1"
    tools:layout_constraintTop_creator="1">
    <LinearLayout
        android:id="@+id/linearLayout"
        android:orientation="horizontal"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:padding="5dp"
        android:paddingEnd="5dp"
        android:paddingTop="5dp"
        android:paddingLeft="5dp"
        android:paddingRight="5dp"
        >
    </LinearLayout>
</ScrollView>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`LinearLayout` doesn't support the concept of wrapping to the next line if something wouldn't fit.

For a small number of fixed items, the best solution is probably to use one of the many "FlowLayout" libraries available when you do a google search.

For a large number of items (or items that you don't know about at design time), you can use `RecyclerView` with a `GridLayoutManager`.

Comment: Consider [FlexboxLayout](https://github.com/google/flexbox-layout) - it can be used both for manual layout of a small number of items, or tied into RecyclerView.